# How to inject simple text to Google search results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, label

I am learning Javascript and would like to build a Chrome extension to add a small text along with the search results like the image below:

[image: Sample UI]

I have a manifest.json and content.js script build:

[image: Manifest.json]

My problem is the content.js - I might be overcomplicating things but any guidance will be appreciated.

```
 const para = document.createElement("labeling1");
    const newContent = document.createTextNode("Sustainable");
    para.appendChild(newContent);
    const currentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
    document.body.insertBefore(para, currentDiv);
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an HTMLCollection, which is "only" an array-like object. </nitpick>

Comment: @boytonic If you're wondering why someone downvoted your question: Probably because you posted a screenshot of code. You're not supposed to do that on SO, you're supposed to show the code itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your console should output the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.

Your content.js is mostly correct so change the last currentDiv to currentDiv[0].

content.js

```js
const para = document.createElement("labeling1");
const newContent = document.createTextNode("Sustainable");
para.appendChild(newContent);
const currentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
document.body.insertBefore(para, currentDiv[0]);
```